How to force re-run service worker without changing source?
How can I restart already registerd service worker?
For example, when I install and activate a sw script that simply prints hello, world! to the console, it does not printed again when I refresh page. This is expected behavior. But how do I force re-run service worker for debugging purpose?

The best way is to check Update on reload in devtool. (Application > Service workers)

